# Calculating derivative of trinomial using the function as a parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, derivative

I need to calculate the derivative of a trinomial function in another function using the former as a parameter. This is my code so far:

```
def derivative(func):
    num=func(a,b,c)
    third=func(0,0,c)
    first=func(a,0,0)
    return (num-third)/x+first/x

 def make_quadratic(a, b, c):
    return lambda x: x*x*a+b*x+c
```

I suppose that by using the `make_quadratic` function I had to add 3 parameters `(a,b,c)` in func as well. What I am trying to do is remove c, divide with x and then add ax so that the resulting derivative is 2ax+b, I cannot however run the code since for some reason a,b,c are not defined even though I do give them values when I call the function.

Comment: You do not define `a`, `b`, or `c` in `derivative`, and that is where the error is complaining you are using them. Did you mean to get them as parameters?

Comment: yes, when i try to run the code by typing: derivative(make_quadratic(1, 2, 1))
I give a, b and c the values of 1,2,1 respectively. Don't I?

Comment: No, you are passing to derivative the result of make_quadratic(1,2,1), which is a `lambda` function - this is what `func` will equal. There is no `a=something` or `a` in the argument of derivative, hence it does not exist there. Please try to go over the basics again, and then return to improve the question.

Comment: Thank you, but I feel as if i do not know what to look for, could you maybe direct me to as to what I should study/ look into again?(ex. functions as parameters)

Comment: Perhaps try and elucidate what you are expecting derivative to return - a function? if so, what does it accept and how does it work?

Comment: I meant the basics of defining functions etc... these are in any text book or walkthrough. It should be clear to you why the interpreter is complaining before you continue coding so you do not get stuck in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Write yourself a class like the following one:

```
class TrigonomialFunction:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c

    def calculate(self, x):
        return self.a * x ** 2 + self.b * x + self.c

    def derivate(self):
        return TrigonomialFunction(0, 2 ** self.a, self.b)

    def __str__(self):
        return "f(x) = %s x**2 + %s * x + %s" % (self.a, self.b, self.c)
```

Which can then get used in the following way:

```
f = TrigonomialFunction(2, 3, -5)
print(f) # will return f(x) = 2 x**2 + 3 * x + -5
print(f.calculate(1)) # returns 0
print(f.calculate(-1)) # returns -6

derivateOfF = f.derivate()
print(derivateOfF) # returns f(x) = 0 x**2 + 4 * x + 3 which can be simplified to f(x) = 4*x + 3
print(derivateOfF.calculate(0)) # returns 3

derivateOfderivateOfF = derivateOfF.derivate()
print(derivateOfderivateOfF) # guess ;)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the derivative of any function using [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html).

For your function, you can use:

```
import sympy

def get_derivative(func, x):
    return sympy.diff(func, x)

def make_quadratic(a, b, c):
    x = sympy.symbols('x')
    func = a * x**2 + b * x + c
    return func, x

func, x = make_quadratic(1, 2, 3)
print(get_derivative(func, x))
```

Which returns `2*x + 2`